# How can I fix 'Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was trying to insert values to MySQL database with following code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project;charset=utf8;, 'admin', 'password');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO userdata values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
if ($stmt->execute(null, '"'.$_REQUEST['username'].'"', '"'.$_REQUEST['password'].'"', '"'.$file.'"', null)) {
echo 'Inserted'
} else {
print_r ($stmt -> errorInfo());
}
```

However, when I run this code, the output says:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

and I can't add any values to the MySQL database.
I made the MySQL database with followinig code:

```
drop database if exists project;
create database project character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
grant all on project.* to 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
use project;

create table userdata (
userid int auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(30) not null,
password varchar(30) not null,
avatar varchar(30) not null,
profilepage varchar(30)
);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.execute.php) accepts a single array, not a variable number of arguments

Comment: Do you really want literal quotes wrapping your stored values? That seems... _odd_

Comment: Please tick the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this.

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project;charset=utf8;', 'admin', 'password');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO userdata (username, password, avatar, profilepage)
        values(?, ?, ?, ?)');
if ($stmt->execute([$_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password'], $file, null])) {
echo 'Inserted'
} else {
print_r ($stmt -> errorInfo());
}
```

1. execute needs an **array**, hence the []
2. **userid** is autoincrement, so there is no need to pass it
3. You have to tell it the **fieldnames** that correspond with the values
4. You don't need the extra **quotes**.

Answer (score 0):

`PDOStatement::execute` accepts one parameter of type `array`. ([Read](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php))

Try this way

```
$stmt->execute([null, '"'.$_REQUEST['username'].'"', '"'.$_REQUEST['password'].'"', '"'.$file.'"', null])
```